# HTML5 Canvas render glitch

Tags: html, canvas, cordova

I'm having an issue with drawing an image on a canvas (and would appreciate some help) :)

I'm building an app that let's the user select an image and then draw on it. I'm using a canvas to render it all. The problem is this: when I've selected an image I draw the image on the canvas (which is centered on the screen) but as you can see in my screenshot it draws it twice - one of them is OUTSIDE of the canvas (window position 0,0).

Is this a glitch in the android webview??

(I'm using Cordova/Phonegap 2.7)

HTML:

```
<div class="box_canvas box_canvas_doodle shadowbox50">
<canvas id="canvas_doodle" />
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT (snippet):

```
$(".box_canvas_doodle").css( "left", Math.floor(($(window).width()-image_resized_wid)/2) );
$(".box_canvas_doodle").css( "top", Math.floor(($(window).height()-48-image_resized_hei)/2) );

// Clear
doo.ctx.doodle.clearRect(0, 0, doo.canvas.doodle.width, doo.canvas.doodle.height);

// Draw image
doo.ctx.doodle.drawImage(doo.imageElem, 0, 0, doo.imageElem.width, doo.imageElem.height, 0, 0, doo.canvas.doodle.width, doo.canvas.doodle.height);
```

[Screenshot http://storage.rejh.nl/_stored/Screenshot_2013-07-25-08-36-53.png](http://storage.rejh.nl/_stored/Screenshot_2013-07-25-08-36-53.png)

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think I found the problem. As in many cases "position:relative;" has some weird consequences. I've set it to "position:absolute;" (for the div 'box_canvas_doodle' that wraps the canvas) and now it renders the canvas correctly.

...html why are you such a &^&#^()__*@

Answer (score 0):

Ok that workaround also broke after a while (no clue why). I rebuilt it now, made the canvas fullscreen and just drew the image in the center (instead of moving the canvas) and the header on top of that. Shees.